# Enviar una lista de objetos con su archivo respectivo - angular 8

Tags: c#, angular

Buenas a todos tengo un problema que no sé como resolver, necesito enviar desde Angular una lista en donde cada registro tenga un archivo adjuntado.
Esta es la clase:

```
export class Generico{
 GenericoId:number;
 GenericoNombre: string;
 GenericoArchivo: File;
}
```

Y este es el componente donde se maneja la lista completa. Pero puntualmente en el método **insertarGenericos()** es donde se realiza la petición al servicio REST.
Actualmente creo un **FormData** sin embargo serviría para solo para un registro de la lista.

```
    export class GenericoComponent{
      genericos : Generico[] = [];
      generico = new Generico();
      positionN: number = 0;

     constructor(private renderer: Renderer,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private http: HttpClient
      ) {  }

    agregarGenerico(){
        this.genericos.push(this.generico);
        this.generico = new Generico();
      }

      insertarGenericos(){
        let formData = new FormData();
        this.http.post('localhost:4200/api/Generico',this.genericos).subscribe(r=>{console.log(r)});
      }

      capturarArchivo(evento){
        this.generico.GenericoArchivo = <File> evento.target.files[0];
        console.log(this.generico.GenericoArchivo);
      }

    }
```

Comment: primaso, lo que estás buscando hacer es ¿enviar una lista de registros donde cada uno tiene un archivo? ¿O cómo?

Comment: ¡Exacto primo, no pudiste describirlo mejor!

Comment: Editia la pregunta y agrega la vista y el componente que tienes